# Node Server Running on Ubuntu that needs to execute a C# application - how?

Tags: c#, c++, node.js, child-process

I have a very simple C# application that was written by a previous person. It uses the MD5CryptoServiceProvider to compute hash using some seed strings to generate a random code.

I have a Node.js server running that I'd like to execute this app and consume the output.

I cannot figure out how to run C# from Ubuntu and I cannot find an MD5 library that comes up with the same answer.

Here is the entirety of the function:

```
{

  MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

  byte[] encodeBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(seed1+ seed2+ seed3);

  byte[] output = md5.ComputeHash(encodeBytes);

  string result = string.Format("{0:D}{1:D}{2:D}{3:D}{4:D}{5:D}",

                                ((output[0] + output[1]) % 10), ((output[2] + output[3] + output[4]) % 10),

                                ((output[5] + output[6]) % 10), ((output[7] + output[8] + output[9]) % 10),

                                ((output[10] + output[11] + output[12]) % 10), ((output[13] + output[14] + output[15]) % 10));

  return result;

}
```

Is it possible for me to modify this C# script to run as a child process or get the same answer using a C++ script, which I have gotten to run with a Node server previously.

Thank you!!

Comment: Wouldn't a better solution be to just convert the C# code to Javascript?

Comment: You have to limit yourself to one problem per question. Either ask, how to start an spawn an application form node exchange data with it, ask how to get a C# program to run on Ubuntu, or ask how to implement the given code in nodejs.

Comment: npm has module for MD5 https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-md5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just convert your code to Javascript:

```
function generateCode() {

  let seed1 = 'abc';
  let seed2 = 'def';
  let seed3 = 'ghi';
  let hashed = md5(seed1 + seed2 + seed3);
  let values = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < hashed.length; i += 2) {
    values.push(parseInt('0x' + hashed.substr(i, 2)));
  }

  let codeParts = [((values[0] + values[1]) % 10), ((values[2] + values[3] + values[4]) % 10),((values[5] + values[6]) % 10), ((values[7] + values[8] + values[9]) % 10),((values[10] + values[11] + values[12]) % 10), ((values[13] + values[14] + values[15]) % 10)];
  let code = codeParts.join('');
    alert(code);
}

generateCode();
```

I used the md5 implementation from [here](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5) but any that returns the hex as a string should work.

[Javascript sample](https://jsfiddle.net/jtpxvm12/)

[C# for comparison (same seed)](https://rextester.com/QLYLC47893)

You could of course simplify this, but this serves as a demonstration of how easy it is to simply convert the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can run C# files on Ubuntu by using mono and mcs, i think they work really well. Here is [a tuturial link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/running-c-sharp-code-into-ubuntu-os1) on how to do it.

TL;DR:
First you will need to install Monodevelop. This can be done with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:directhex/ppa  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

After installing mono you will need to install mcs:

```
sudo apt-get install mcs
```

When both are installed correctly you need to make a .cs file (a C# file). You can compile the program with mcs (`mcs <filename.cs>`). Then use mono to execute the generated exe file: `mono <filename.exe>`.

Comment: If you write an answer then it has to be self-contained, so a reader is able to solve the problem even if external links go down. As of that link only answers are not sufficient.